# how to short url by using google firebase dynamic link if the url contains '#'

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener, short-url

i am using firebase dynamic link to shorten my url but on doing so its gives the response of   "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM" as my url contails '#' sign. and its generates the short url of the data before # and ignores the data after #.

My url is mentioned below:-

"https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com/#/xyz/pqr/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.aTExSk5la3ZMUVUwTGU2ZTA3OThrdFRkVXE3ZThUZ0lZNzdpckVDcDhSRkIrZHBSUDl0ZFU0SlJOUkYwN0hwYXp2aUF4RlVZZjlTdGYzRnVJWlZpTlRxUDJvWlhyWVhCemJHa1VDc053Sm0vRmlYZlh4bGRb2xjcHM1RmhhdktkY2dRa1RhUlFPQjIya0Z2bWJSeEQ4YVFhY2FtSlJUOGFVMVR5ZUhOZm54Zz09.dhDJWIz9gqmnbhRhkwgZolwNZ8ba4CCjDEYlefkilPc"

i am calling api:-

https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=my-key

Comment: why would a hashtag be a directory? That seems to be counter to standard web practice as a hastag usually points to a section of a page. ...maybe I simply don't understand your framework/architecture though...

Comment: @ Ron Royston Jun : yeah but this is legacy project and we can't change it right now. is there any other way to short this url.

Comment: replace the `#` with `---` before passing it to the API?

Answer (score 0):

encode the url first before passing it to the api end point